# Avoid storing null values when skipping an iteration in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

**Exist a way to avoiding to store null values in an iterative process when some condition is activated to skip to the next iteration?** *The intention of "how to solve" this problem is with the structure itself of the loop*

[**CONTEXT**]:

I refer to the case when you need to use a storing mechanism inside a loop in conjunction with a conditional statement, and it is given the scenario where basically one of the possibles path is not of your interest. In the honor to give the treatment in the moment, and not posterior of the computation, you skip to the next iteration.

[**EXAMPLE**]

Suppose given a certain sequence of numbers, I interested only in stored the numbers of the sequence that are greater than 2 in a **list**.

```
storeGreaterThan2 <- function(x){
y <- list()
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        if (x[i] > 2) {
            y[[i]] <- x[i]
        } else {
            next
        }
    }
y
}
```

The previous function deal with the final purpose, but when the condition to skip the iteration is activated the missing operation in the index is filled with a null value in the final list.

```
> storeGeaterThan2(1:5)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5
```

**In the spirit of dealing with the problem inside the structure of the loop, how it could deal with that?**

Comment: Inside your loop use the index length(y)+1 to add an additional element, such as this: `y[[length(y)+1]]<-x[i]`.  Depending on your desired results there are several better and faster ways than to use a for loop.

Comment: This is a good solution to lead with the problem of the NULL values in the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather strange example, and I wonder if it's an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  It may be better to say more about your situation and what you ultimately want to do.  For example, there are different ways of trying to do this depending on if the function's input will always be an ascending sequence.  @Dave2e's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591592/how-to-avoid-storing-null-values-when-i-skip-an-iteration-in-a-for-loop-r/40593614#comment68419125_40591592) that there will be better ways depending of what you are really after is right on the mark, in my opinion.  At any rate, you can simply removed the `NULL` elements before you return the list.  Consider:

```
storeGreaterThan2 <- function(x){
  y <- list()
    for(i in seq_along(x)) {
      if(x[i] > 2) {
        y[[i]] <- x[i]
      } else {
        next
      }
    }
  y <- y[-which(sapply(y, is.null))]
  return(y)
}
storeGreaterThan2(1:5)
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5
```

---

Here is a possible way to do this without ever having stored the `NULL` element, rather than cleaning it up at the end:

```
storeGreaterThan2 <- function(x){
  y <- list()
  l <- 1                   # l is an index for the list
  for(i in seq_along(x)){  # i is an index for the x vector
    if(x[i] > 2) {
      y[[l]] <- x[i]
      l      <- l+1
    } 
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Comment: It's not a x-y problem @gung. I edit my answer to give more context.

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar, fair enough. Would poping the element at that point in the loop be what you are looking for? Would you be willing to use a different counter to track the element of the list vs the element of x?

Comment: Your answer solve the problem. In conecction with the comment of @Dave2e, the use of length(y)+1 also solve the problem, and capture what I was trying to say: avoid the storing of the null values in the same loop syntax.
I wil try to edit the answer to be more explicit with this. I don't have a background in a formal programming, but the main intention of the question is how to deal this problem with the structure itself of the loop

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar, OK, I see what you mean now. I guess I had misunderstood what you were asking for at first.

Comment: Your last approach inside the loop does not have dependency in other function like `length()`. This is what I looking for, exist another approach in this line? (just for curiosity) @gung

Comment: There are lots of possibilities, I suppose, @CristóbalAlcázar. I may not think of them, though. Is it guaranteed that `x` will always be an ascending sequence like `1:5`?

Comment: My example only made spotlight in a specific problem that appeared when I used a loop. In fact, I am working in a function to scan files in a `path` to import all the xls and xlsx files that are there and store each one as a component in a list. But sometimes exist more types of files in the `path` and the for loop skip this when detected that not belong to a xls or xlsx files. The extraction of the null values in the same for,  made the code more structured.

Comment: In that case, I would probably use the 2 indexes (`i` & `l`), @CristóbalAlcázar.